# Publishing results from shell script onto Jenkins

Tags: html, jenkins

I have a regression build script which builds 90+ modules . The script maintains a list of what passed and what failed. Is there a plugin or easy waorkaround to display the status of those 94 modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes -- you can **use the [JUnit plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin)** to do that. Despite its name, it's not tied to unit testing alone.

The plugin can

- display the success status of individual sub-tests
- give a "failed since" indication for failed sub-tests
- provide summary statistics on total passed/failed count over builds

Only caveat: you must **convert your result list to JUnit XML format**, so the plugin can process this as input data. The format is rather straightforward, though, and conversion should not be much effort.